# Bootstrap 4 <ul> in tab-content of dynamic nav-tab breaking layout

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I am using the dynamic nav-tabs in Bootstrap 4 and adding content to each tab. Once I added an unordered list to the first tab, navigating away from that tab breaks the layout (shifts horizontally). I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

edit: new jsfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/jayefive/e6z70pb8/

If you un-comment the `<ul>` the layout break occurs.

Comment: `If you un-comment the <ul> the layout break occurs.`... I can't see any commented `ul` in your code..

Comment: also not sure why the comment tag isn't sticking in jsfiddle... its the 2 `<ul>`s just below `<h4>Services Header</h4>`

Comment: I'm using your fiddle and there is no error, it works fine...

Comment: Even after un-commenting the `<ul>`s? You don't see the content shifting to the left about 10px? Then jumps back after clicking on another tab? Now I'm really confused.